# Twilio IBM Watson Speech To Text Addon Callback function not getting triggered

Tags: node.js, twilio, ibm-cloud, speech-recognition, ibm-watson

My objective is to get transcribe (Caller's input - IVR Conversation) using IBM Watson Speech to Text Addon which is available on Twilio platform (Twilio Add-ons feature).

IBM watson speech to text add-on is installed.

**Problem:** Callback function which defined on Callback URL is not getting triggered.

I have followed the guidelines mentioned on this [link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/add-ons/tutorials/how-to-use-recordings-add-ons-in-nodejs)

I have configured my Programmable voice application as web hook function. (Using NGROK) and Callback function is also configured as a web hook.

**Callback URL Configuration**
[image]

I can see request landing to /voice and /recording, but the requesting is not landing to /callback. Source code is below

```
    const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const axios = require('axios')
const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.post('/voice', (req, res) => {
  const twiml = new VoiceResponse()

  twiml.say('Hi! I want to know what do you think about coding. One')
  //twiml.record({maxLength: '10', action: '/callback'})
  twiml.record({maxLength: '10', action: '/recording',playBeep:false})
  twiml.hangup()

  res.send(twiml.toString())
});

app.post('/recording', (req, res) => {
  const twiml = new VoiceResponse()
  const recordingUrl = req.body.RecordingUrl

  twiml.say('Thanks for howling... take a listen to what you howled.')
  twiml.play(recordingUrl)
  twiml.say('Goodbye.')

  res.send(twiml.toString())
})

app.post('/callback', (req, res) => {
  const addOns = JSON.parse(req.body.AddOns)

  if (!('ibm_watson_speechtotext' in addOns.results)) {
    return 'Add Watson Speech to Text add-on in your Twilio console'
  }

  const payloadUrl = addOns.results.ibm_watson_speechtotext.payload[0].url
  const accountSID = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID
  const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN

  axios.get(payloadUrl, {auth: {username: accountSID, password: authToken}})
    .then(response => {
      const results = response.data.results[0].results
      const transcripts = results.map(item => item.alternatives[0].transcript)
      return transcripts
    })
     .then(transcripts => res.send(transcripts.join(' ')))
})

app.listen(1553);
```

What configuration am i missing ?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem right now.  It's acting as if I never enabled the addon.

Comment: I'm not sure if you figured anything out here, but it looks like you've done the right thing, so I'd recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to report the issue with the add-on.

Comment: @philnash Thanks for your feedback. I have already reported this to Twilio Support team.

Comment: Great, thanks for letting me know, hope they get you sorted quickly!

Comment: Any updates? Faced same issue

Comment: @MichaelKapustey: There was some issue on integration between twilio and IBM watson. It was fixed by the support team. After that it worked for me.

Comment: I just recently hit this exact same issue.  I have ticket in with support, but if anyone came across a solution that I can apply since the last comment, I'd love to see it.

Comment: @JohnL If you are facing exact same issue and assuming you have got all the configurations correctly, then IMHO you wouldn't be able to do much to fix this. If there is an integration issue between Twilio and IBM watson, it has to be fixed by them. Please wait for feedback from support.

Comment: No, it was a stupid configuration issue. But having this post helped.

Comment: @Subin_Learner I do have a follow up question that you might be able to answer. Given the translation is completely async, but doesn't appear to contain anything to link it to the call, how do you associate a particular call with this call back?

Comment: @JohnL : Whenever a call session starts, it will be given a unique call id (Call SID). This Call SID will be available as part of HTTP request if i am not wrong. That way you can associate the call. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: what is Callback URL here, how to get this ?

Comment: Its a webhook, you have to create one. You can google to find more information about it.