# Watson speech to text not triggering callback

Tags: node.js, twilio, ibm-watson

I've been using the Watson add-on.  Over the past few days it seems to have stopped triggering the callback.  I've verified that my callback function works by substituting the Voicebase transcription add-on.

Is there another way to use the Watson transcription service from Twilio serverless runtime functions?

I did find that there was a similar issue posted back in November.  This would indicate to me that the add-on is unstable.

[Twilio IBM Watson Speech To Text Addon Callback function not getting triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53118160/twilio-ibm-watson-speech-to-text-addon-callback-function-not-getting-triggered)

Comment: Hey there, sorry you're experiencing this with the add-on. As I suggested on the previous question, your best bet is to get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) who will be able to investigate this for you.

Comment: Hi @philnash, I have been in contact with Twilio support who had to put a ticket in with the Watson team. The add-on works wonderfully when it actually works, and I wasnt sure if anyone had experience with using Watson directly without the use of the add-on. I can see where it would be called from the status callback associated with an individual number, but I havent delved into using the Watson api directly.

Comment: I've worked with the Watson API to do sentiment analysis on incoming SMS messages (before we had add-ons) and it was fairly straightforward.

Comment: @philnash, in that context would a separate IBM Watson account be required, or can the existing account from Twilio still be utilized?  Any suggestions for starting points would be appreciated if you recall them.

Comment: You will need your own IBM cloud account. I'd start off taking a look at their example project: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text-nodejs